# Extruding "Ramps" into Geometry

Tags: topology, extrude

I'm currently working on a machine gun and I need to detail the front of it. What it requires is sort of "ramps" on this section.
This is my nozzle thus far:

[image: Nozzle]

And here is an image in which the nozzle of a real gun has ramps. As you can see, they extrude into the mesh and slope in towards the center. The ends are rounded but that's not of concern.
[image: MG3 Machine Gun]

I'm basically trying to achieve this, but all the way around the nozzle. I know how to do it one by one, and I know how to checker deslect and extrude, but I can't think of a clean or time efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

[image: Desired Ramp Geometry]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using "Spin Duplicates"

Create 1 of the "ramps" and delete the rest of the faces
[image]

Then use the Spin Duplicates tool to spin the selected faces around the 3D Cursor.
It takes a little getting used to, but it's a good tool for this kind of thing.
[image]

There will be some clean up so be sure to Merge by Distance the result (I had to bump up the default distance to clean it up well)

Comment: That's done it! Thank you. Never used that tool before but seems handy.

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun, you could do it procedurally.

1. Add *Array modifier*
2. Add *Simple Deform Modifier > Bend > 360°*
3. Add Weld Modifier to merge the start/end vertices.

[image]

You can also non-destructively adjust the radius by moving the Origin point.

[image]

Comment: While I can see this being useful for some situations, I'm hoping to not have to restart the geometry I already have. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: @PlanetAlexanderProjects Oh, sure, this was mostly for fun :).